# How do I exec my docker container from an azure function

Tags: c#, powershell, docker

I'm wondering how do I run/exec a started container.
I can use CLI from a command line, but in real world situations containers are called from other instances of code to perform the job they are good at.
I'm particularly looking for C# or PowerShell scripts issued from Azure Functions.
How can this be done - incl. links to documentation?

Comment: Where do you run your containers?

Comment: From within Azure Containers